# How to let textbox only english can be input like type="password"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textbox

For example , I have three input mode (Chinese , Japanese , English)
When I input at the type = "password" , only English can be used and I can't change the input mode.
Now I want my textbox like this but not use type = "password",only english mode can be used , how can I do it ?

Comment: Are you saying "I only want English to be used." or "For some reason the password field is only using English."

Comment: Yes, as you say, "I only want English to be used", sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There is really no way to do it. You can add an event listener and check if the character is in a range of characters.

Comment: thanks for your advance, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

it is a component that you use everywhere

```js
const MultiLangualInput= ({lan}) => {
    const EnglishMode = (event) => {
        let flag = false;
        var cahrcode = event.charCode;
        flag = (cahrcode == 32) ||
        (48 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 57) ||
        (65 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 90) ||
        (97 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 122);
        if (!flag)
            event.preventDefault();
    }
    const otherLanguage = (event) => {
        console.log(event.charCode)
        let flag = false;
        var cahrcode = event.charCode;
        flag = (cahrcode == 32) ||
        (48 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 57) ||
        (65 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 90) ||
        (1570 <= cahrcode && cahrcode <= 1594);
        if (!flag)
            event.preventDefault();
    }
    return (
        <Input onKeyPress={lan==='en'?EnglishMode:otherLanguage}>

        </Input>
    );
};

export default MultiLangualInput;
```

**Like this:**

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
    <MultiLangualInput lan='en'>
        
    </MultiLangualInput>
  );
};
```

Comment: sorry for my bad English, I mean that when I put something into the textbox, it can be like type = "password", only English can be input and when I want to change the input mode, only English mode can be selected.

Comment: For example, I use the Japanese mode at another textbox, when I input something at this textbox, it can be auto turn to English mode.

Comment: it is a component you can change "lan" when ever you want

Comment: good job , thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, if the answer helped, please accept it.

Comment: Sorry for that I have no 15 reputation to cast a vote , after when I get enough reputation， I will back to cast a vote.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly something like this should work

in your HTML

```
<textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Write something here</textarea>
```

in Javascript

````
let text = document.querySelector('textarea');

const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9()*_\-!#$%^&*,."\'\][]+$/;

text.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{

  if(!pattern.test(text.value)) {
    alert('please use only latin letters')
  }

})```
````

Comment: sorry for my bad English, I mean that when I put something into the textbox, it can be like type = "password", only English can be input and when I want to change the input mode, only English mode can be selected.

Comment: For example, I use the Japanese mode at another textbox, when I input something at this textbox, it can be auto turn to English mode.